# Python Flask Jinja SQL: No value being passed to template

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

In my GET portion of the Flask function I'm working on I have some very simple code written in Python 3.  The data I'm trying to pass in is never displayed on my HTML render.

```
@app.route("/sellselected", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sellselected(order_num):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #not done, just have a redirect to index
    else:
        stock_to_sell = db.execute("SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE order_num = :order_num", order_num=order_num)
        #stock_to_sell = ['fish']

    return render_template("sellselected.html", stock_to_sell=stock_to_sell, order_num=order_num)
```

The SQL statement seems to passing in nothing, it's just blank on the HTML render.  But as a test I also used 'fish' and it's None/empty too.

Jinja looks like:

```
{% block main %}
<list>
    <ul>{{ stock_to_sell }}</ul>
    <ul>{{ order_num }}</ul>
</list>
{% endblock %}
```

So the body of the page has the order number, but stock_to_sell is always empty.

Comment: You are passing a list; is that your intention? What happens if you pass just `'fish'`?

Comment: Yes, the jinja was more complicated with a for and list, but I simplified until I can get stock_to_sell to render.  'fish' doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to jinja anymore. Your route is wrong, it should be: `@app.route("/sellselected/<order_num>", methods=["GET", "POST"])`.

Because you pass order_num to sellselected function so you need to declare it on route.

Comment: That didn't work.  I put everything on github.  Maybe I'm leaving out some key piece of info.  https://github.com/jamesdylangoldstein/finance

Answer (score 0):

You say you like to pass the param order_num as GET right? Because the code say POST is redirect to index.

So, you pass the param as GET. You need to get it first

current_order = request.args.get('order_num')

Your code should be:

```
@app.route("/sellselected", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sellselected(order_num):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # not done, just have a redirect to index
    else:
        order_num = request.args.get('order_num')
        stock_to_sell = db.execute("SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE order_num = :order_num", order_num=order_num)

return render_template("sellselected.html", stock_to_sell=stock_to_sell, order_num=order_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware if you iterate over an object then it's contents will comeback empty. This is because the result is a generator, and it's values can be accessed only once.

**Won't work as gcp_certs has been iterated over:**

```
  gcp_certs = connection.execute(query)
  for cert in gcp_certs:
     print(cert.name)
    
  return render_template('certifications.html',
                           gcpcerts=gcp_certs,
                           now=datetime.utcnow(),
                           cookie=token)
```

**Works:**

```
  gcp_certs = connection.execute(query)
  return render_template('certifications.html',
                           gcpcerts=gcp_certs,
                           now=datetime.utcnow(),
                           cookie=token)
```

**One solution:**

```
imports copy

gcp_certs = list(connection.execute(query))
sql_select = ''
for cert in copy.copy(gcp_certs):
     print(cert.name)

return render_template('certifications.html',
                           gcpcerts=gcp_certs,
                           now=datetime.utcnow(),
                           cookie=token)
```